# Extract Text Between Multiple Parentheses

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract, parentheses

Please help me with extracting Values between brackets and form an output String.

Sample: Aspirin (150mg) + Atorvastatin (10mg) + Clopidogrel (75mg) Capsule

Desired Output : 150mg + 10mg + 75mg

Thank You

Comment: What about other data. All data are same pattern?

Comment: Depending on your data it might be relatively simple to create an UDF making use of `RegEx`, with pattern: [`\d+mg`](https://regex101.com/r/A2wP5r/2) or include the plus sign [`\d+mg|\+`](https://regex101.com/r/A2wP5r/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below formula but it is based on your example. Need to adjust `Num_Chars` parameter if data length in `parentheses` are different.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,5) & "+" & MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1)+1,4) &"+"&MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1)+1)+1,4)
```

[image]

> You can use below formula if data length is always `4 or 5 character` in parentheses.
>
> `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,5) & "+" & MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1)+1,5) &"+"&MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1)+1)+1,5),")","")`

Comment: Thank you Harun for your valuable reply. In my Data the Parentheses length varies and number of parentheses in each cell may also vary. Please help me with these examples also. Epinephrine (1mg) Injection|
Glimepiride (1mg) + Metformin (500mg) + Voglibose (0.2mg) Tablet|
Methylcobalamin (1mg) + Vitamin-B6 (100mg) Injection

Comment: Did you try my second formula?

Answer (score 2):

Another option to use TEXTJOIN function, and together with the INDEX+FILTERXML to force the array formula into a shorter and normal formula,

and the FILTERXML function return an array without error/blank cells, so the IFERROR() is not necessary

Then in `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN("+",1,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,")",""),"(","<r/>")," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]"),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Very smart use of `INDEX` and `FILTERXML` :-)

Comment: @bosco_yip This solution worked perfectly... Thank You bosco_yip...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative if you have access to `TEXTJOIN` formula. You need to enter it using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (convert it to an array):

```
=TEXTJOIN("mg + ",TRUE,IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",255)),"mg)",REPT(" ",255)),1+255*ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),255))*1,""))&"mg"
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Justyna for your valuable reply. In my Data the Parentheses length varies and number of parentheses in each cell may also vary. Please help me with these examples also. Epinephrine (1mg) Injection| Glimepiride (1mg) + Metformin (500mg) + Voglibose (0.2mg) Tablet| Methylcobalamin (1mg) + Vitamin-B6 (100mg) Injection

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My formula should already do exactly that :) see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/mRd416c.png)